# Entity Framework Core - Skip & Take result in multuple queries with SELECT TOP(1)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, paging

I'm fetching records from AzureSQL using EF with paging (skip & top).
Code:

```
     var query = _context.Kits
            .Include(k => k.KitStatuses)
            .Where(t => t.X == y)
            .OrderBy(t => t.Z)
            .Skip(skip)
            .Take(pageSize).Select(t => new
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Barcode = t.Barcode,
              ...
            }).ToListAsync();
```

The probelm is that there should be only one query with SELECT TOP(pageSize) but in profiler I can see 1 query per record (on the included KitStatuses table):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [k3].[Updated]
FROM [KitStatuses] AS [k3]
WHERE ([k3].[Status] = 1) AND (@_outer_Id1 = [k3].[Kit_Id])',N'@_outer_Id1 uniqueidentifier',@_outer_Id1='868780F2-C121-C209-65F1-08D4442D5A8A'
```

Any ideas why?

If I do not include child collection it works fine (1 query).

Thank you & kind regards,
H3k0

Comment: Try using join instead of include

Comment: This seems to be a defect in current EF Core implementation.

Comment: what version of ef core you used? please add complete query!